# How to Keep second last li active in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have simple tab control in my MVC application

View

```
    <div class="span12" id="test" style="width: 810px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active" id="li1"><a href="/#tab1"  data-toggle="tab">New Stream1</a></li>
            <li><a id="addspan" href="/#C" data-toggle="tab">+</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabbable">
            <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                   tab content
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var count = 2;
        $('#addspan').click(function () {
            $('li:last').prev().after('<li id="li' + count + '"><a href="/#tab' + count + '"data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>');
             $('li:last').removeClass("active");
            $('li:last').prev().addClass("active");

        });

    });
</script>
```

after click on "addspan" or(+) li i have added one li dynamically before last li, so my query is after click on (+) li it add ".active" class to that li, but i want to keep newly added li is active, how i can do?

one more scenario i have observed, after adding following code in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var count = 2;
            $('#addspan').click(function () {
                $('li:last').prev().after('<li id="li' + count + '"><a href="/#tab' + count + '"data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>');

                 //to keep newly added li active

                 $('li:last').removeClass("active");
                $('li:last').prev().addClass("active");

            });

        });
    </script>
```

it working fine it added ".active" class to second last li,but after completing javascript function it again ".active" class to last li,i don't know why this happen?

please let me know how i can set ".active" class to newly added LI?

Comment: are you using jquery UI tabs or something else ? Can you make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var $li = $('<li id="li' + count + '"><a href="/#tab' + count + '"data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>');

// Remove the previous active li class
$('li.active').removeClass("active");

// Add active class to new li
$li.addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
var count = 2;
$('#addspan').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('li').removeClass("active");
   $('li:last').prev().after('<li id="li' + count + '"><a href="/#tab' + count + '"data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>');
   $('li:last').prev().addClass("active");
});
```

Do these:

1. try to stop the default behavior `e.preventDefault()`
2. remove the class `.active`
3. add the new li
4. then assign the `.active` class

#### [CHECKOUT THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q6Pb/)

---

Or this one:

```
var count = 2;
$('#addspan').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('li').removeClass("active");
   $('li:last').prev().after('<li class="active" id="li' + count + '"><a href="/#tab' + count + '"data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: it's no working for me, means when control is within click event it work after control goes from click function again it set .active class to last li.

Comment: `_please let me know how i can set ".active" class to newly added LI?_` isn't id doing this?

Comment: your code is work properly but after loss control from click event, i think it again set .active class to last li from some another javascript function, so is there any to prevent that one?